How would you say "to dream" as in "to see in a dream" in Latin?
In Croatia, Novi Fosili have a song that starts with:

Sanjala sam da te više ne volim.
Sanjala sam i u snu sam plakala.
Sanjala sam, sanjala, da odlazim.
Plava me zora vratila.

I would translate it to English as:

I dreamed that I no longer loved you.
I dreamed and, in my dream, I cried.
I dreamed, I dreamed, that I was leaving.
Blue dawn returned me.

So, how would you translate that to Latin? Would you translate "to dream" as "in somnio videre"? Here is my attempt:

In somnio videbam me iam te non amavisse.
In somnio videbam et in somnio lacrimabam.
In somnio videbam, videbam, me abivisse.
Livida aurora me remisit.

Is that correct?

FWIW, NVG Mt chapters 1 & 2 use in+plural abl. five times: in somnis apparuit, responso accepto in somnis, admonitus in somnis. The singular is only used once, seemingly referring to waking up: Exurgens a somno.

Plus, does the tense vidi match the Croatian sense? At least from the English it is suggested it could. That way you can save a syllable. In somnis me vidi...

@Rafael Yes, I think "vidi" would also work here.

Not what you asked about, but it seems to me that the infinitives should be present (amare, abire) instead of perfect (amavisse, abivisse)

@cnread I thought they had to be perfect because of the consecutio temporum.

@FlatAssembler, The tense of a present infinitive is with repect to its governing verb. So imperfect verb plus a perfect infinitive yields a pluperfect sense. A perfect verb with a present infinitive yields a perfect sense.

@Rafael: Isn't that about somnus "sleep" rather than somnium "dream, vision"?

@Cerberus you mean exsurgens a somno? I guess so, yes.

@Rafael: All of your examples have somnus "sleep" rather than somnium "dream, vision", don't they?

@Cerberus Now I see your point. I'm sorry, you're right. But it is still valid that NVG Mt prefers somnus even for what one sees in sleep.
